# Hibernate re-inserts full collection when merging

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to understand hibernate a bit better after spending already quite some time on a One to many relationship I want to establish.

So currently my application works, i.e. I can add children (DocTemplateArguments) to the parent (DocumentTemplate). What bothers me is that hibernate is not **updating** the child records when I set them through the parent, it actually **inserts and deletes** them every time again I execute a merge. 
As you can see, I have already updated the equals and hashcode by only keeping the relevant fields for the business logic. So, as long as the name of the child is not updated in the set that is being used for the initialisation of parent, I want hibernate to execute an update statement instead of an insert/delete combo.

Please find some code snippets below:

**Parent**

```java
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "document_template")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude="docTemplateArguments")
public class DocumentTemplate {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = true, length = 100)
    private String description;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, length = 15)
    private DocumentType type;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "format", nullable = false, length = 15)
    private DocumentFormat format;
    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false, length = 50000)
    private String content;
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "documentTemplate", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<DocTemplateArgument> docTemplateArguments = new HashSet<DocTemplateArgument>();

    public void setDocTemplateArguments (Set<DocTemplateArgument> dtas){
        this.docTemplateArguments.addAll(dtas);
    }
}
```

**Child**

```java
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "doc_template_argument")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"DocumentTemplate","id","dialogText"})
public class DocTemplateArgument {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column (name="name", nullable = false, length=30)
    private String name;
    @Column (name="dialog_text", length = 100)
    private String dialogText;
    @Transient
    private String argument;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name="doctemplate_id", nullable=false)
    private DocumentTemplate documentTemplate;
}
```

From my current understanding I think I need to intervene in the merge method of the DAO class of the parent in order to get this done. This currently looks as follows:

```java
@Repository
public class DocumentTemplateDAOImpl implements DocumentTemplateDAO {
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public DocumentTemplateDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<DocumentTemplate> getAll() {
        List<DocumentTemplate> documentTemplates = getCurrentSession().createQuery("from DocumentTemplate").list();
        return documentTemplates;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public DocumentTemplate get(int id) {
        return getCurrentSession().get(DocumentTemplate.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void create(DocumentTemplate documentTemplate) {
        getCurrentSession().persist(documentTemplate);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update(DocumentTemplate documentTemplate) {
        getCurrentSession().merge(documentTemplate);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(int id) {
        DocumentTemplate documentTemplate = get(id);
        getCurrentSession().delete(documentTemplate);
    }

    private Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

I have no idea on how to do this though, any help would be greatly appreciated.

For completeness, the whole structure is being called in a convertToEntity method of a DTO:

```java
    public static DocumentTemplate convertToEntity(DocumentTemplateDTO documentTemplateDTO) {
        DocumentTemplate documentTemplate = new DocumentTemplate();
        documentTemplate.setId(documentTemplateDTO.getId());
        documentTemplate.setName(documentTemplateDTO.getName());
        documentTemplate.setDescription(documentTemplateDTO.getDescription());
        documentTemplate.setType(documentTemplateDTO.getType());
        documentTemplate.setFormat(documentTemplateDTO.getFormat());
        documentTemplate.setContent(documentTemplateDTO.getContent());
        documentTemplateDTO.getDocTemplateArguments().stream().forEach(dta -> dta.setDocumentTemplate(documentTemplate));
        documentTemplate.setDocTemplateArguments(documentTemplateDTO.getDocTemplateArguments());
        return documentTemplate;
    }
```

**EDIT**
I found out why this happened. In my request I was omitting the id of the argument. I presume that when the json is deserialised it defaults a non specified property of type integer into 0, which then as such ended up in the entity. 
When I put this to the latest id for the record to be updated, it properly issues an update statement. Still, I find this a bit counterintuitive when the id is explicitly excluded from the equals and hash check with:

```java
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"DocumentTemplate","id","dialogText"})
```

If would be great if someone can explain this!

Comment: Can you clarify the issue, is it only that you don't want the insert/delete because its costly (or similar problem) or are you having problems like id's of `DocTemplateArgument` entities changing because they get created as new entries.

Comment: I would like to be in control of how the application behaves on the persistence side. I intend it to do updates instead of inserts and deletes, or at least learn how I can achieve that kind of behavior.